# How can I make a rectangle with text in the center in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner and I'm currently learning how to make a simple graphic for a program that will make a rectangle and it has text inside and it can receive a user input. But I do not know how to put the text inside the rectangle.

## Here is the code that I used

```
    int Menu() {
    int userInput;
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 80; ++column)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << "\n";

        for (int row = 0; row < 8; ++row)
        {
            cout << "*";
            for (int column = 0; column < 78; ++column)
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << "*\n";
        }
        for (int column = 0; column < 80; ++column)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    
    cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
    cout << "\n\t      CONVERTER MENU";
    cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
    cout << "\n1. Convert Decimal";
    cout << "\n2. Convert Binary";
    cout << "\n3. Convert Octal";
    cout << "\n4. Convert HexaDecimal";
    cout << "\n5. Exit Converter";
    cout << "\n--------------------------------------------";
    cout << "\n Enter the number of your choice: ";
    cin >> userInput;

    return userInput;
}
```

### Here is the output of my code

[image: Output of my current code]

```
****************************
*                          *
*                          *
*                          *
****************************
Text right here:
```

#### Here's how I want the output to be

```
****************************
*                          *
*    Text right here:      *
*                          *
****************************
```

Comment: Can you write down in English/pseudocode what you want to do? Break it down into individual steps.

Comment: If you're writing to, say, a terminal, you're going to need to know the text you want in your rectangle before you print out the rectangle. You'll have to explicitly do finicky stuff in the inner loops to figure out when to print a line that looks like:
```*     Text right here:              *```

Comment: Can you use C++20?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/zjnsa5xeT

Comment: @MarekR Looks nice. Can you also achieve so that inside `*`-window there will be input cusor reading any input string?

Comment: @Arty For what you are attempting to do, this gets very tricky (ie, near impossible) using only C++'s standard I/O functionality. What you really need is to use platform-specific console/terminal APIs to manipulate the input/output at the OS level, in which case you should use a 3rd party (n)curses library that wraps that functionality for you and is compatible with your program's supported platform(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution would be:

- to use a vector of strings for the lines you want to print, and then
- divide and conquer!
  I.e., printing a set of lines with a border can be accomplished by printing first the top border, then each line with right and left borders, and, finally, the bottom border.
  Just use different functions for each small part of the problem and you are half way there.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/EEesdY7P5)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <string>
#include <vector>

size_t get_longest_text(const std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    for (auto& line : lines)
    {
        if (line.size() > ret)
        {
            ret = line.size();
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

void print_border_top_or_bottom_line(size_t longest_text)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < longest_text + 4; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "*";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void print_second_top_or_second_bottom_line(size_t longest_text)
{
    std::cout << "*";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < longest_text + 2; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "*";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void print_line(const std::string& text, size_t longest_text)
{
    std::cout << "*";
    std::cout << " ";
    std::cout << text;
    std::cout << std::string(longest_text + 1 - text.size(), ' ');
    std::cout << "*";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void print_lines_with_border(const std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{
    size_t longest_text = get_longest_text(lines);
    print_border_top_or_bottom_line(longest_text);
    print_second_top_or_second_bottom_line(longest_text);
    for (auto& line : lines)
    {
        print_line(line, longest_text);
    }
    print_second_top_or_second_bottom_line(longest_text);
    print_border_top_or_bottom_line(longest_text);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> lines{"Blah", "Foo foo", "Third line", "And so on and so forth"};
    print_lines_with_border(lines);
}

// Outputs:
//
//   **************************
//   *                        *
//   * Blah                   *
//   * Foo foo                *
//   * Third line             *
//   * And so on and so forth *
//   *                        *
//   **************************
```

Now, you could extend this code, for example, to allow the use of:

1. different output streams,
2. different characters, horizontal and vertical, for the border, or
3. text alignment.

You can get some ideas on how to do that in this other implementation below.

---

A decorated printing function would fit well here. We would basically have:

- a `print_lines` function that would print a variadic number of arguments, one per line, and
- an `add_border` decorator that would receive 1) the function above to print the lines, and 2) a series of configuration parameters (e.g. characters to use for the top and bottom, and right and left borders, alignment, and so on).

The decorator would:

- calculate the length of the longest argument,
- print the top and second lines of the border,
- grab each argument, decorate it by adding borders to each side, apply and alignment, and call `print_lines` to print all the decorated lines, and
- print the second to bottom and bottom lines of the border.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/497b7cxj1)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // max
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <string>

enum class text_alignment{ left, centered, right };

template <typename Printer>
constexpr auto add_border(char h_char, char v_char, text_alignment alignment, Printer&& print_args)
{
    return [h_char, v_char, alignment, print_args = std::forward<Printer>(print_args)] (std::ostream& os, auto&&... args) {
        auto to_string = [](const std::string& str) {
            return str;
        };
        auto align_text = [](const std::string& text, auto line_size, auto alignment) {
            auto [blanks_before_text, blanks_after_text] = [&text, line_size, alignment]() -> std::pair<size_t, size_t> {
                size_t blanks_size{line_size - text.size()};
                switch (alignment)
                {
                    case text_alignment::left:
                        return {1, blanks_size - 1};
                    case text_alignment::centered:
                        return {blanks_size / 2, blanks_size / 2 + (blanks_size % 2)};
                    case text_alignment::right:
                        return {blanks_size - 1, 1};
                    default: return {};
                }
            }();
            return std::string(blanks_before_text, ' ') + text + std::string(blanks_after_text, ' ');
        };
        auto decorate_text = [align_text, alignment, v_char](const auto& text, auto longest_text_size) {
            return std::string{v_char} + align_text(text, longest_text_size + 2, alignment)  + v_char;
        };
        auto print_top_or_bottom_line = [h_char, &os](auto longest_text_size) {
            os << std::string(longest_text_size + 4, h_char) << "\n";
        };
        auto print_second_top_or_second_bottom_line = [decorate_text, &os](auto longest_text_size) {
            os << decorate_text("", longest_text_size) << "\n";
        };

        auto longest_text_size = std::max(std::initializer_list{(to_string(args).size())...});

        print_top_or_bottom_line(longest_text_size);
        print_second_top_or_second_bottom_line(longest_text_size);

        print_args(os, (decorate_text(to_string(args), longest_text_size))...);

        print_second_top_or_second_bottom_line(longest_text_size);
        print_top_or_bottom_line(longest_text_size);
    };
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto print_lines = [](std::ostream& os, auto&&... args) {
        ((os << args << "\n"), ...);
    };

    constexpr auto print_star_bordered_text = add_border('*', '*', text_alignment::left, print_lines);
    print_star_bordered_text(std::cout, "Blah", "Foo foo", "Third line", "And so on and so forth");
    std::cout << "\n";
    constexpr auto print_hash_bordered_text = add_border('#', '#', text_alignment::centered, print_lines);
    print_hash_bordered_text(std::cout, "Blah", "Foo foo", "Third line", "And so on and so forth");
    std::cout << "\n";
    constexpr auto print_dash_bordered_text = add_border('-', '|', text_alignment::right, print_lines);
    print_dash_bordered_text(std::cout, "Blah", "Foo foo", "Third line", "And so on and so forth");
}

// Outputs:
//
//   **************************
//   *                        *
//   * Blah                   *
//   * Foo foo                *
//   * Third line             *
//   * And so on and so forth *
//   *                        *
//   **************************
//   
//   ##########################
//   #                        #
//   #          Blah          #
//   #        Foo foo         #
//   #       Third line       #
//   # And so on and so forth #
//   #                        #
//   ##########################
//   
//   --------------------------
//   |                        |
//   |                   Blah |
//   |                Foo foo |
//   |             Third line |
//   | And so on and so forth |
//   |                        |
//   --------------------------
```